# Undefined reference when linking libpq in C++ project

Tags: c++, postgresql, vcpkg, libpq, libpqxx

I am trying to use `libpqxx` (and implicitly `libpq`) in a C++ project.
I use `vcpkg` as a `submodule` to get my libs by setting `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`.

When I try to build, I get the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libpq.a(fe-auth.o): in function `pg_fe_sendauth':
fe-auth.c:(.text+0x4fe): undefined reference to `pg_md5_encrypt'
/usr/bin/ld: fe-auth.c:(.text+0x51b): undefined reference to `pg_md5_encrypt'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libpq.a(fe-auth.o): in function `pg_fe_getauthname':
fe-auth.c:(.text+0x838): undefined reference to `pqGetpwuid'
/usr/bin/ld: fe-auth.c:(.text+0x8a4): undefined reference to `pg_strerror_r'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libpq.a(fe-auth.o): in function `PQencryptPassword':
fe-auth.c:(.text+0x936): undefined reference to `pg_md5_encrypt'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libpq.a(fe-auth.o): in function `PQencryptPasswordConn':
fe-auth.c:(.text+0x9ed): undefined reference to `pg_md5_encrypt'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libpq.a(fe-auth-scram.o): in function `build_client_final_message':
fe-auth-scram.c:(.text+0xdb): undefined reference to `scram_SaltedPassword'
/usr/bin/ld: fe-auth-scram.c:(.text+0xee): undefined reference to `scram_ClientKey'
/usr/bin/ld: fe-auth-scram.c:(.text+0xfe): undefined reference to `scram_H'
/usr/bin/ld: fe-auth-scram.c:(.text+0x113): undefined reference to `scram_HMAC_init'
/usr/bin/ld: fe-auth-scram.c:(.text+0x12d): undefined reference to `scram_HMAC_update'
/usr/bin/ld: fe-auth-scram.c:(.text+0x141): undefined reference to `scram_HMAC_update'
/usr/bin/ld: fe-auth-scram.c:(.text+0x15b): undefined reference to `scram_HMAC_update'
/usr/bin/ld: fe-auth-scram.c:(.text+0x16f): undefined reference to `scram_HMAC_update'
/usr/bin/ld: fe-auth-scram.c:(.text+0x185): undefined reference to `scram_HMAC_update'
/usr/bin/ld: fe-auth-scram.c:(.text+0x195): undefined reference to `scram_HMAC_final'
/usr/bin/ld: fe-auth-scram.c:(.text+0x1e4): undefined reference to `pg_b64_enc_len'
/usr/bin/ld: fe-auth-scram.c:(.text+0x213): undefined reference to `pg_b64_encode'
/usr/bin/ld: fe-auth-scram.c:(.text+0x344): undefined reference to `pg_b64_enc_len'
/usr/bin/ld: fe-auth-scram.c:(.text+0x368): undefined reference to `pg_b64_encode'
...
```

I have broken down the linking command here:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/hello-pq.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++     CMakeFiles/hello-pq.dir/CMakeFiles/3.16.3/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp.o CMakeFiles/hello-pq.dir/main.cpp.o  
-o ../bin/hello-pq  
/home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libssl.a 
/home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libcrypto.a 
/home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libpqxx-7.3.a 
-lpthread 
/home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libpq.a -ldl
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../third-party/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
        CACHE STRING "Vcpkg toolchain file")

project(hello-pq)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED) 
find_package(libpqxx CONFIG REQUIRED)

file(GLOB_RECURSE PROJECT_SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
                        PRIVATE OpenSSL::SSL 
                        PRIVATE OpenSSL::Crypto
                        PRIVATE libpqxx::pqxx)
```

I looked at the `libpq.a` from `vcpkg` *installed* dir with `nm` and I can see that for example, `pg_md5_encrypt` appears as **undefined**:

```
U pg_md5_encrypt
```

I don't get it, where are these missing functions like `pg_md5_encrypt`?
Is there another `libpq...` that I need to link or maybe a different version?

Comment: The order of the libraries etc may affect things. Put the ones required by others before the ones that require them and your own code last. But you still have two `main`s there also

Comment: `GLOB_RECURSE` seems to be picking up `CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp` from your build directory, its probably not a good idea to use `GLOB_RECURSE` in the root of your project

Comment: Yes, you are right, I will fix that now and update in order to get that error out of the way.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I have tried already to put libpq before libpqxx and I am getting `undefined reference` errors for `libpqxx`, e.g.: in function pqxx::encrypt_password[abi:cxx11](char const*, char const*):
.../connection.cxx:98: undefined reference to PQencryptPassword

Comment: I think I am missing some lib that I need to link as I am linking statically, but what throws me off is the fact that some `undefined reference` errors are for functions like  `pg_md5_encrypt` which start with `pg_` so I assume they should be part of the `libpq` or some other `postgres` lib and not some external lib that I might be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging around and testing I found that there are 2 more `postgres` static libraries that I need to link:

- libpqcommon.a
- libpgport.a

Additionally, the link order is also important and altough I was expecting to have to pass `libs that are needed` before the `libs that need them`, this is not the case here and it feels backwards.
Here is a working linker command:

```
usr/bin/c++ CMakeFiles/hello-pq.dir/src/main.cpp.o \
-o ../bin/hello-pq \
/home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libpqxx-7.3.a \
/home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libpq.a \
/home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libpgcommon.a \
/home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libpgport.a \
/home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libssl.a \
/home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libcrypto.a \
-lpthread \
-ldl
```

In order to link the extra 2 static libs and also to achieve the order above, I updated the `CMakeLists.txt` like so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../third-party/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
        CACHE STRING "Vcpkg toolchain file")

project(hello-pq)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED) 
#find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED) # Not needed (it will duplicate the libs)
find_package(libpqxx CONFIG REQUIRED)

file(GLOB_RECURSE PROJECT_SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
                        PRIVATE libpqxx::pqxx
                        PRIVATE PostgreSQL::PostgreSQL
                        PRIVATE OpenSSL::SSL 
                        PRIVATE OpenSSL::Crypto)
```

This translates into the following linker command:

```
/usr/bin/c++ \
CMakeFiles/hello-pq.dir/src/main.cpp.o \
-o ../bin/hello-pq \
/home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libpqxx-7.3.a \
/home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libpq.a \
/home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libssl.a \
/home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libcrypto.a \
/home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libpq.a \
/home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libpgport.a \
/home/user/work/cxx-playground/third-party/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libpgcommon.a \
-ldl \
-lpthread
```

We can see that `libpq.a` appears twice in the link arguments:

- once due to `libpqxx::pqxx` target (I assume)
- once due to `PostgreSQL::PostgreSQL` target
  which also contains the 2 missing static libs that need to be linked (`libpgport.a` and `libpgcommon.a`).

My conclusion is that this is a `libpqxx` bug, which should also link those 2 static libs with `target_link_libraries(PUBLIC...)` in the only target that it exposes (`libpqxx::pqxx`)

Comment: libpqxx is probably not linking against the target PostgreSQL::PostgreSQL but just the library libpq.

Comment: Ah it is using ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES}. looking at the cmakelists.txt this is a bug in vcpkg-cmake-wrapper.cmake which does adjust the target but does not fix the PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES variable